# How to customize product details page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, product-view

I have setup a Magento store using ***Magento 2.1.3*** and I want to customize ***product details page***. I have attached a screenshot. Can anybody give me some suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you created your custom theme?
If yes, you make changes in these file.

> magento2.3/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
>
> magento2.3/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Comment: ok i search these files

Comment: Here i not found magento2.3/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

Comment: @MohdHasan you can override file from /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml